# Is something happening with the tag counts recently?

Tags: support, tags, reputation

Lately I've noticed that the score on my `[html5-canvas]` tag has been falling without explanation.

A while back (maybe 2 months?) it was 957 then dropped to 922 and is now 902.
This might be happening on other tags too, but I haven't paid that much attention. My total rep did not drop along with the tag score reduction so I'm at a loss to explain.

So...Just curious...What's up with the counts recently?

Comment: Some questions you answered with that tag may have had the tag edited out. (Just a guess, I have zero data to prove that's what happened in this case.)

Comment: Or deleted.  And tag score, not count.  You used to post several answers a day, it is down to a couple a week.  You don't lose rep when the post was old enough.  There is no good way to verify.