# Can these questions with changed tags be returned to their original tagging?

Tags: support, edits, tag-badges

Is there a way for a moderator track down changed tags and restore them?

**Why I ask...**

I’m trying to get my gold [html5-canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-canvas) tag badge and in March I noticed that my score in that tag unexpectedly went down from 950+ to 902. I posted an inquiry [on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318222/is-something-happening-with-the-tag-counts-recently) back in March. The unexpected badge score drop does not seem to be related to deleted questions.

Today, I again noticed that my [html5-canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-canvas) tag score went unexpectedly went down from 953 to 932 and I tracked down that the cause is retagging of questions out of their original `html5-canvas` tags.

Please note that almost all my answers do relate to [html5-canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-canvas) (I keep to a small corner on Stack Overflow) so there was no reason to remove that tag from any of those questions.

Is there a way for a moderator (or SQL dev) to track down all these changed tags and restore them (not just the ones I've found so far)?

**Update** The tags have been restored.

Comment: Note that your first link to "his higher scoring answers", he didn't add the tag. The editor before him did that. Granted, neither did he remove it so he's not being consistent on using it.

Comment: What a cool idea to keep the competition down. brb, going on an edit spree

Comment: Seems like a pretty devious thing to do in any case :(.

Comment: The acts of the user in question gives me an odd feeling of shame, anger, hatred and smirk.

Comment: *You almost have a gold-badge for one tag (`html5-canvas`). Now you almost have a gold-badge for two tags!!! (`html5`, `canvas`)*

Comment: Whats the difference between `canvas` and `html5-canvas`? Seems like they are the same. At least the description of `canvas`says it means the HTML5 canvases. I'd just make one of them an alias of the other one.

Comment: @hichris, neutering the link to the user doesn't bring much to the table when their profile is readily accessible from the review links, I'm afraid (and please don't go and remove those, the pitchforks are already out anyway).

Comment: @tkausl. The html5-canvas tag is for browser based questions about the Canvas element added with Html5. The Canvas tag is more general and includes the Android Canvas. The questions involved here are all for the html5-canvas tag -- none of the questions involve the more general canvas tag.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi But the focus is now on the *behavior*, not the user. It's okay to call out questionable behavior, it's not okay to call out users.

Comment: @hichris, you think? :) Such despicable behavior from a user with their reputation is rare enough to trump that rule I'm afraid. Human nature and all. Yet, I agree we should aim to contain that within reasonable proportions.

Comment: @markE The description of `canvas`: "Canvas is a drawing element introduced to web development with HTML5. For Android or WPF, use android-canvas or WPF-controls." See: [canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/canvas/info). If this is for both, HTML5 _and_ Android canvas, it should be rephrazed. I don't see why we need a tag for two completely different techniques though.

Comment: We're aware, and investigating. No pitchforks, please.

Comment: Just rollback the edits and get your badge? They guy won't do this anymore according to the mode above ^

Comment: @tkausl. Agreed that one single `canvas` tag is less confusing then the two different tags -- I'd certainly go for combining the 2 tags.

Comment: @meagar. Thanks for the help. **No pitchforks intended**, just want tagging fairness -- nothing else. And the user in question is a good & valuable member of the small `canvas` area of Stackoverflow. He is also (based on my  interaction with him on Stackoverflow) a decent person.

Comment: @markE If you know this guy and value his contribution, why didn't you just ping him in chat? You didn't need to call him out this way. I don't say you did something wrong here, but doing this would minimize the expose of this dispute.

Comment: @markE HATS OFF to you sir..yes this is absolutely fraud. SO should take care about that.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi is right the user is already out there, no point in hiding it. Leave it with the powers that be to decided the outcome though.

Comment: Funny thing is that you have 817 answers that are tagged with `html5` *and* `canvas` but not `html5-canvas`

Comment: @PatrickHofman The user might not participate in chat.

Comment: @Lankymart I explained up above "the focus is now on the *behavior*, not the user." Meta exists as a platform to discuss the site. It shouldn't be a mob attacking any user who does something wrong.

Comment: @PatrickHofman - I also think there's value in having at least one Meta post about an issue like this. It hadn't even occurred to me that tag/badge fraud could even be a thing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Have we discovered someone committing fraud? No.

The party in question, K3N, has [explained the reasons for his edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326818/734069), and they do not appear to be fraudulent. That is, they do not appear to be intended specifically to benefit himself and/or to harm others.

However, that doesn't mean that K3N's actions were OK. It may not have been the fraud that was alleged, but his explanation for his edits still showed bad behavior.

Specifically, there are two tags that both mean the same thing. Instead of merging, unifying, or aliasing those tags, K3N's explanation was that he was trying to turn one of them into a *dumping ground* for crap questions. He was very clear about this in his post: he wanted to put what he considered to be low-quality content into one of the tags.

That isn't fraud, but it *is* bad behavior. So while we didn't find someone defauding the system, we did find someone acting improperly on the site.

Comment: Agreed. I also now believe there was no fraud intended.

Comment: "Instead of merging, unifying, or aliasing those tags".. right. That has [been attempted more than 4 years ago](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253790/1693593) with no result what so ever. I am trying again [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326855/1693593) and it doesn't look optimistic.. any other suggestions?

Comment: And are you saying it's better to use *two* identical (context wise) tags as " dumping ground for crap questions" (your words, not mine) instead of just one? (for the exact same content). The post itself does not loose any of its context description by removing one tag when it's identical (and most other posts has only one tag no?).

Comment: I am not making an excuse, but I can't see any sense in this...

Comment: @K3N: Two wrongs don't make a right. As I stated before, tagging based on the quality of a question or answer is *not acceptable*. We tag for *content*, not quality. A question that is about the HTML5 canvas is about the HTML5 canvas no matter its quality. So while you may have meant well, what you did was still against the rules.

Comment: @K3N: "*I am trying again here and it doesn't look optimistic..*" You made that requires *40 minutes ago*. Did you honestly expect legions of people to come out of the woodwork and instantly start retagging questions? Large-scale retagging *takes time*. So I would say you're jumping the gun about how "optimistic" it looks. If nothing's been done after a week, then pessimism may be well-founded.

Comment: @NicolBolas "You made that requires 40 minutes ago" see the *links* posted in the thread...

Comment: "Two wrongs don't make a right." I didn't say that either (and my focus was discoverability, not the quality although that was the trigger). But no worries, I'll stay away from tag editing for a while and will let the feedback from this thread sink in.

Answer (score 45):

I had a bit too much time at my hands and analyzed the tag editing history of user K3N regarding the HTML5-Canvas tag from today back to April 15th.

- I added `OK` when the removal was not influencing the score of either `markE` or `K3N`.
- I added `markE` when the question has an answer by `markE`
- I added `markE(x) < K3N(y)` when the question has an answer by both
  `markE` and `K3N` with the respective score in brackets.

**Removed HTML5-Canvas:**

```
markE?    Asked by?        OK?  Question?
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
markE | Deepu S A        |    | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19229319/to-rotation-an-image-in-canvas-using-mouse
markE | Lucy             |    | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17064913/display-tooltip-in-canvas-graph
      | Andre Ferraz     | OK | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37876567/limit-access-to-socket-end-point
      | 3rdEye           | OK | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37786061/show-checkbox-on-canvas
      | Torgia           | OK | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37529734/fabricjs-edit-child-path-inside-object
markE | Hope Tsai        |    | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37328583/drawing-multiple-squares-on-the-canvas
markE | Colin747         |    | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824747/overlay-html5-canvas-over-image
markE | acampbe222       |    | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36972276/how-to-make-drawing-move-using-canvas-and-javascript
      | Tisha            | OK | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36802481/fabric-mouse-events-not-triggered
      | Christian Memije | OK | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36779301/set-an-image-to-fill-the-canvas-using-paper-js
      | Sophie D         | OK | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36769801/fabric-js-drag-circle-along-a-line
      | Katie Sak        | OK | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36731389/hide-and-than-show-a-div-jquery
      | Stephen Amsel    | OK | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36698575/ruby-selenium-web-driver-to-manipulate-objects-on-a-canvas
      | Ed Jones         | OK | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19017401/how-to-store-and-retrieve-image-to-localstorage
      | eskalera         | OK | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36604335/fabricjs-paths-not-rendering-until-mouseup
      | Rakib Ahsan      | OK | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36660982/fabricjs-canvas-inside-angular-material-tabs-doesnt-work
      | user3377450      | OK | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36632714/charts-js-not-using-the-right-colors
```

**Kept HTML5-Canvas:**

```
   markE?             Asked by?         Question?
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                   | chudasamachirag | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37947259/export-image-from-canvas-in-printing-size-300-dpi
                   | user1937021     | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36956962/make-arbitrary-line-dashed
                   | Nolesh          | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20015817/disable-html5-canvas
                   | user1526912     | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36893937/how-to-crop-from-a-scaled-image-and-keep-the-aspect-ratio-of-the-original-image
                   | lerouche        | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36883037/generate-a-thumbnail-snapshot-of-a-video-file-selected-by-a-file-input-at-a-spec
                   | BitUnderflow    | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36898084/input-box-not-selectable-over-html5-canvas
                   | blank_kuma      | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29812524/trying-to-remove-border-of-arc-on-canvas
markE(3) < K3N(6)  | CaiNiaoCoder    | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21050014/html-canvas-art-generate-coordinates-data-from-sketch
                   | AndyJ           | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16738438/why-does-chrome-struggle-to-display-lots-of-images-on-a-canvas-when-the-other-br
                   | Shaun314        | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19869150/getimagedata-cross-origin-error
                   | Dharun          | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17937516/detect-if-canvas-css3-animations-are-being-optimized-when-not-visible-and-outsid
markE(1) < K3N(10) | irie            | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835070/create-gradient-for-color-selection-with-html5-canvas-all-possible-rgb-colors
                   | user4501328     | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28978648/how-to-fill-certain-percentage-area-of-circle-in-color-in-html-canvas
                   | Narando         | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18954116/html5-drag-and-drop-path-on-canvas-without-js-library
                   | Lin             | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19175174/capture-frames-from-video-with-html5-and-javascript
                   | BBnyc           | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038440/canvas-clipping-with-feather-edges-effect
                   | A Gilani        | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17835066/division-sub-canvas
```

**Added HTML5-Canvas:**

```
    markE?            Asked by?         Question?
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                   | mat       | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36977589/slitting-html5-canvas-video-element-into-pieces
markE(1) < K3N (2) | Chris     | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36774063/create-a-polygon-around-a-line
                   | kannanrbk | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36601915/smooth-color-transition-between-multiple-color-stops
```

## Conclusion:

During the analyzed time period...

- User K3N removed the HTML5-Canvas tag from 17 questions and in 12 cases its removal was warranted. In all the remaining 5 cases where removal was **decreasing the score of markE**, the question was answered by markE.
- User K3N kept the HTML5-Canvas tag in 17 cases and in all these cases, the question was **not** answered by markE **OR** the score of markE's answer was lower than the score of K3N's answer.
- Whenever user K3N added the HTML5-Canvas tag, the question was **not** answered by markE **OR** the score of markE's answer was lower than the score of K3N's answer.

Comment: What's your criteria for when the changes were warranted and why should we believe it? Also the score of markE's post in each question would be a great addition to this data to add some additional context. (Did K3N intentionally target his highest scoring answers? Random ones? Recent ones? etc.)

Comment: @TylerH feel free to update. I added the link of each question to allow everyone to check for themselves if they agree with the given judgement. Basically all OK edits were removals of HTML-Canvas from fabric.js questions.

Comment: I replaced 'warranted' by the more objective 'not influencing the score of either markE or K3N'.

Comment: @le_m This doesn't look suspicious at all... Oh, and only one of the five edits didn't have accompanying changes. [One that did](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19229319/revisions) screwed up the syntax of a code snippet and [another](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37328583/revisions) wasn't really that constructive IMHO (changing the title + adding irrelevant `object` tag). And for [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17064913/revisions), there was no need to remove the link. [The last one](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14824747/revisions) was rather trivial (although it was ok IMHO)

Comment: Correction: I missed the third example (the link) because the diff doesn't tell you there's a link... :-(

Comment: Is that a *[conclusion](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/conclusion)*?

Answer (score 43):

<strike>Yes, this is pretty clear fraud. He is removing the tag [html5-canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-canvas) from questions, only to replace it with [html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5) and [canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canvas) , while at the same time adding [html5-canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-canvas) to questions he has answered</strike>

As a subject-matter expert in [html5-canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-canvas) (he has a gold badge in it), it's highly unlikely that this is unintentional.

If he were simply removing the [html5-canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-canvas) tag from questions that had nothing to do with it, it might be technically OK. But replacing the tag with two separate tags kind of rules that possibility out.

---

Update:

On closer inspection, the edits in OP's post *adding* the tags each happened way back in 2014. K3N has since responded by saying he was editing the tags purely to make them easier to search.

While I don't see how replacing a specific, unambiguous tag with two broader, partially ambiguous tags would *improve* searchability, the defense plus my realization in the paragraph above means this is not necessarily fraud (which is, simply, deceit for personal gain).

I'm sorry for accepting (and running with) the charged language of the OP's title (fraud) and assuming that the examples he posted were all recent; I made a bit of an ass of myself.

Comment: Your honor, this is a high-rep user who knows exactly what he's doing. I'd like to request suspension for one year. `</pitchfork>`

Comment: BTW Which would be the proper tagging in these cases? [tag:html5] + [tag:canvas] vs [tag:html5-canvas] vs all three?

Comment: @totymedli In my opinion, [tag:html5-canvas] is the most appropriate one since it details exactly the language feature being used. I'm not an expert in it, however. [tag:canvas] is a bit more ambiguous and [tag:html5] is a broad, broad tag.

Comment: @TylerH actually the tag problem is even deeper, both the OP and incriminated user only have knowledge in the [CanvasRenderingContext2D API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D), while the [web-gl API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API) is also based on the canvas element, and shares only a [few methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement#Methods). And there are also some questions related to some particular HTMLElement (which are mainly answered as "*don't use CSS to resize it*")

Comment: bravo for the ass admission and +10 for being decent enough to stand up and say that rather than dig a bigger hole as many do! :D

Answer (score 11):

If this user is in fact adding and removing tags from posts just to game the badge system and be the only user with the gold [html5-canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-canvas) badge, then I would say yes, this is fraud and unacceptable.

The way I see it, you have a few options while we wait for an official mod response:

1. Flag one of the posts in question with a custom mod flag explaining the situation.
2. Come to Meta to present your findings (which you've nicely and politely done).
3. Roll back the edits which remove the tag, or add the tag back.  If you see the user continue to edit and remove the tag, flag for a content lock from a mod.

Comment: [@meagar♦](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/229044/meagar) has already rollback a lot of the users edits related to [tag:html5-canvas].