# Users 'fake' editing questions to gain reputation and question editor status

Tags: support, edits, abuse

I first noticed this when I was a lurker of Stack Overflow, and now it happened to one of my posts.

Users will edit some very small changes into a question and eventually revert the edits just to become an 'editor' on the question. Has anyone else noticed this happening, do you get points for doing this?

[Here is the revision history of my latest question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45406873/revisions), notice the user changes some very small things and then reverts the entire question back to its original state.

Personally this is kind of aggravating because the question was pretty fine as it was (IMHO) and it seems the user is trying to get attribution for modifying my question.

Comment: Users with more than 2k reputation don't get any rep for edits, so that can't be the reason.

Comment: Maybe to qualify for gold badge status to dupe hammer things?

Comment: @fbueckert nope, the dupe hammer is reserved for gold *tag* badges.

Comment: @Glorfindel Yeah.  I'm not sure of the requirements for them, but it may be worth seeing what is related between the edits.  Maybe they're under the assumption that edits increase their tag participation?

Comment: @fbueckert I doubt it, they seem to be pretty familiar with how Stack Exchange works.

Comment: @Glorfindel Well, a quick glance at their most recent edits show them editing in the html5-canvas tag.  Then editing it out.

Comment: @fbueckert wait. That reminds me of [this Meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326743/4751173), but on closer inspection, those a different users.

Comment: @Glorfindel yeah exactly, if it was just to my post I wouldn't have made a meta post  but it seems this is happening a lot. I have more examples of these users if you want.

Comment: @dieusu no, not here. Please flag one of your own posts (it doesn't matter it's not related to those users) and explain to them what you've found.

Comment: @Glorfindel sounds good, added a link to this post as well.

Comment: There is more to it than meets the eye.  There is a holy war being fought over [html][canvas] vs [html5-canvas].  Using [everything-and-the-kitchen-sink] tagging is not a very good idea imo, but it appears impossible to talk people out of it.  Looks like this user wrote a program to automatically retag questions, and it had undesirable side-effects in affecting the rest of the post as well.  At least he rolled-back the damage.  Alerting a user that there is a fast moving bus approaching is sensible, done.

Comment: @HansPassant that's a fair assessment, after looking at it a bit that could be the cause.

Comment: I don't think there are any bad intentions here, only a buggy [bot](https://github.com/greggman/fixallthetags) that's still a WIP.

Comment: @HansPassant that [Meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326743/4751173) I linked to is more than a year old. You mean that that's still not settled?

Comment: I think editing a post is good thing to better understanding an OP's question.

Comment: I ran into a similarly suspicious scenario today. Not sure how I should have responded to it. [See this - Version 2](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45529327/revisions)

Comment: @NisargShah That's the question author editing their own post...?

Comment: @BenjaminW. See version 2 - the one with comment: "deleted 168 characters in body"

Comment: @NisargShah Oh, I see. Revision two looks like a good edit to me, though.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Fair enough then. Thanks. At the time the user making the edit had posted an answer to the question, and I had flagged the question as duplicate - which was eventually accepted. I felt that the user had edited the question to prevent it from getting marked as duplicate given that they changed the entire wording of the question.

Comment: Editing the question will push it on the top of the [active questions list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/?sort=active&pageSize=30). That way the question gets more attention, and a user having a good answer in the post might benefit from the growing audience. This also will turn against the editor pretty quickly, if the edits are meaningless.

Comment: User having more than 2K reputation don't get anymore reputation. And for people less than this edit goes to review queque. So reviewer should see through it.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I took a look at that user's history and that's really suspicious indeed. It turns out that they were testing a [script](https://stackapps.com/q/7533/34061); next time, it could be a user trying to get the [Copy Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/223/copy-editor) badge. In any case, because they have more than 2000 reputation, they don't get more reputation out of this.

In cases like this, the best option is to flag your post for ♦ moderator attention. (Normally, flagging requires 50 reputation, but this is not the case for your own posts.) This prevents the user in case from being targeted by the [Meta Effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/235225/295232). Furthermore, moderators have access to more information, and the means to communicate in private with this user to settle this case.

Comment: Your edit of the question gave me a giggle.

Comment: I already have a Copy Editor badge (on Meta); I just like things being tagged appropriately.

Comment: No I understand

Comment: I'm glad. And coming to Meta with this kind of questions is really commendable.

Comment: he has arrived to edit this one, too @gman

Comment: @gman : What is happening? Only you can offer an explanation.

Comment: @George you can click the [edited x hours ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/354516/revisions) link above gman's avatar to see what he changed.

Comment: @gman bots are cool (proof: SmokeDetector) and testing in production (especially when there is no test environment available) is fine. I'm glad you rolled back the changes. This kind of editing behavior is *suspicious*, i.e. out of the ordinary. From the first revision on, I've included the possibility that you don't have malicious intentions, and as far as I can see nobody is accusing you of anything.

Comment: @gman the one thing that I would've done differently, is putting a temporary message on my profile indicating the failed trial run of your script. It took us a while to find the cause now, which might have led people to assume the worst.

Comment: @gman : I empathize with your frustration. I was merely asking if there was an explanation, and wanted you to seek clarification before people assumed anything. I have not idea what happened except the edit history that not only showed the edits to the tags but also edited the special characters with their character codes. Anyway, I feel that your comment could have been better constructed. Peace! :)

Comment: apart from gold tag badge, badges are the last thing people care about afait